# Change the language of voice recognizer in android wear action

Tags: android, localization, wear-os, voice-recognition

In my android app, I create a notification with wear features and add an action to recognize the voice input and send the voice text to another activity. My problem is it just recognize the selected language in google now settings (English) and I want to get voice from the Persian language. This my code:

```
RemoteInput remoteInput  = new RemoteInput.Builder("My_Const_String")
    .setLabel("label when you talk")
    .build();

Intent replayIntent = new Intent(context, MyTestActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, replayIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
NotificationCompat.Action action = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(
        R.drawable.ic_btn, "Label when confirm your talk", pendingIntent)
        .addRemoteInput(remoteInput)
        .build();

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
builder.setContentTitle("Title")
    .setContentText("Content text")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
    .setContentText("My text02");

NotificationCompat.WearableExtender extender =
        new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender();

extender.addAction(action);
builder.extend(extender);

NotificationManagerCompat mgr = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
int NotificatinId = 1;
mgr.notify(NotificatinId, builder.build());
```

Also I don't want to force the user to change the settings of google now manually. I tried to add extra like below but it didn't worked:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, "fa_IR");
i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES, "fa_IR");
i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "fa");
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle = i.getExtras();

RemoteInput remoteInput  = new RemoteInput.Builder("My_Const_String")
    .setLabel("label when you talk")
    .addExtras(bundle)
    .build();
```

Answer (score -2):

Its works fine with French and Russian languages. I think [Persian](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/4492226?hl=en) not support by now. Look at "Languages that work with voice typing" part.

Comment: Persian and Farsi both are the same and It's support by google. On your phone in `Google App>Settings>Voice>Languages` do you have just English check or you checked other languages too?